# Add new common name to Heroku ACM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have SSL working on my heroku app. I started using Heroku SSL and I'm now using Automatic Certificate Management. I'm in the process of migrating an app from one domain to another. www.firstdomain.com is working with SSL. However I'm now trying to add SSL to the new domain, seconddomain.com.

The error I'm receiving from chrome when navigating to the second domain is `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. This makes sense because the output of `heroku certs:auto` the Common Name(s) are: firstdomain.com, www.firstdomain.com, with no mention of seconddomain.com, despite the domain having a status of OK below.

1. Do I need to update the common name to include seconddomain.com?
2. If so, how do I do that using heroku certs?